# Access host web server from guest OS (Hyper-V)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v

I'm using Windows 10 on my host machine and created an Ubuntu 18 Hyper-V VM on it (using the VM template provided by Microsoft). Now I want to access a web server running on the host OS from within the guest OS. The guest OS can access the Internet just fine, but accessing a web server on the host (either via localhost, computer name, or any of the IP addresses the host has) does not work.

I can ping the host using `ping <computername>` just fine. But HTTP(S) access seems to not work. Can this be firewall related?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a firewall problem. By default (or our company's default policies) the guest OS cannot access port 80/443 on the host OS.